# Mutable borrow seems to outlive its scope

Tags: rust

Trying to compile this program I get stuck on the borrow checker:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

type Object<'a> = BTreeMap<&'a str, i32>;

struct Root<'a>(Object<'a>);

struct Sub<'a>(&'a mut Object<'a>, &'a str);

impl<'a> Root<'a> {
    fn borrow_mut(&'a mut self, data: &'a str) -> Sub<'a> {
        Sub(&mut self.0, data)
    }

    fn borrow(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut me = Root(Object::new());
    {
        me.borrow_mut("data!");
    }
    me.borrow();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=02a753dca37ce320ae42c8ce9edda4a4&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

I get:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `me` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
22 |         me.borrow_mut("data!");
   |         -- mutable borrow occurs here
23 |     }
24 |     me.borrow();
   |     ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
25 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

It looks like the mutable borrow should end before `me.borrow()` but the borrow checker insists that it ends when `main` ends.

To quickly explain what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Make a parent struct to hold data
2. Make a sub category of data and store it in the parent
3. Use this builder style pattern to make MongoDB Queries

Comment: Uh? Now that's unexpected, the mutable borrow should be scoped. Oh... unless your lifetimes affect it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are running afoul of a lifetime issue.

There are multiple different lifetimes in your program:

- `type Object<'a> = BTreeMap<&'a str, i32>;` => this is one
- `&'a mut Object<'a>` => there are up to TWO here
- `struct Sub<'a>(&'a mut Object<'a>, &'a str);` => there are up to THREE here

There is, apparently, no reason for the reference to `Object<'a>` to have the same lifetime than the `&str` inside the `BTreeMap`. However, you *told* the compiler that you wanted both lifetimes to be the same!

When you write:

```
struct Sub<'a>(&'a mut Object<'a>, &'a str);
```

you are telling the compiler that:

- the lifetime of the `&str` inside `BTreeMap`
- the lifetime of the reference to `Object<'_>`
- the lifetime of the `&str` accompanying the `Object<'_>`

are all one and the same.

You have over-constrained the requirements; and as a result no solution can satisfy them.

Adding one more degree of freedom is sufficient! We'll just make the lifetime of the reference to `Object<'_>` different from the lifetime of those `&str` floating around:

```
struct Sub<'a, 'b: 'a>(&'a mut Object<'b>, &'b str);

impl<'b> Root<'b> {
    fn borrow_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, data: &'b str) -> Sub<'a, 'b> {
        Sub(&mut self.0, data)
    }

    fn borrow(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.0);
    }
}
```

Note the subtle `'b: 'a`:

- `Object<'b>` contains a reference to something whose lifetime is `'b`
- the lifetime of the reference to `Object<'b>` (denoted `'a`) must be SHORTER than `'b` (otherwise you have a reference to something dead?)

Thus, we say that `'b` outlives `'a` with `'b: 'a`.

And that's it. Simply loosening the requirements allow the compiler to allow your code to compile.

---

Note that in general, if you find yourself writing something like `&'a &'a str` you are doing it wrong. If you think about it, you will realize that in order to create a reference to something, it must first *be*. And therefore a reference to an object *necessarily* has a shorter lifetime than the object itself (ever so slightly).

Comment: Thank you so much! I always wondered how to do that `'b: 'a` constraint. Where is this documented, and where can I learn more?

Comment: The lifetimes in general are explained [in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html) but I could not find the `'b: 'a` syntax there (it might be buried somewhere).

Comment: For anyone who's curious, I only found docs about this in the *nightly* documents [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/subtyping.html).

Comment: @MichaelEden: Well spotted!